# Euler Limit with -1 to infinity?

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left(\frac{4}{x-4}\right)^{1/x}$$
If the problem was $$4-x$$ it would be fine, but it is $$x-4$$ so I end up with $$(-1)^{+\infty}$$ I thought it would be divergent because we can approach infinity by odd numbers and even numbers and on that case, the limit could vanish to a positive number or to a negative number. But my surprise was that when I put that on Wolfram it gave me a limit.

Comment: i think there is no limit

Comment: @lulu I am trying to wrap my head around what you said "x is approaching 4 from he right". I don't get that. x approaches zero from the right and the denominator is then -4, I am not implying (yet) that the limit wouldn't exist...

Comment: @imranfat  My error.  I read the problem as asking for the limit as $x\to 4^+$.    I will delete my earlier comment (and this one in a few minutes).

Comment: I'm just wondering what wolfram told you the answer was.

Answer (score 1):

There is almost surely a mistake in the printing.

I assume you are studying the calculus of real numbers.

The function you are taking a limit at *is not defined* for $x < 4$, since it is in the form of a negative number raised to a power. Even if we decided to use the common extension to allow rational exponents with odd denominator, that still leaves undefined all the places where $x$ is irrational!

While it is possible for some conventions to yet make sense of such a situation, stressing the fine details of such conventions in this sort of way is not something introductory textbooks tend to do.

---

If you did [this calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20(4%2F(x-4))%5E(1%2Fx)%20as%20x%20goes%20to%200%2B) in wolfram alpha, then it didn't give you a limit. What it did was interpret the exponentiation as *complex* exponentiation, 
and then returned to you a whole *set* of *limit points* — the complex numbers of the form $z=\exp\left( \frac{1}{4} + 2 \pi \mathbf{i} t \right)$ where $t$ is a real number ranging over the interval $[0, \pi]$. That is, the set of complex numbers with norm $e^{1/4}$ and nonnegative imaginary part.

The limit only exists in the special case that there is a *single* limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Inverting we have,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(\frac{x-4}{4}\right)^{1/x}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(\frac{x}{4}-1 \right)^{1/x}$$

Interestingly enough if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is written as a simplified fraction with a even denominator then we can rewrite the limit in such case as,

$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)^{1/x}$$

$$=e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$

And so our original limit tends to $e^{1/4}$.

However if $x \in \{ \frac{1}{n} \ \text{where} \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{and is odd} \}$  we may rewrite the limit as,

$$=-\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)^{1/x}$$

And then our original limit will tend to $-e^{1/4}$.

We see the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: And so our original limit tends to....the exponent of the e-power is negative, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what what you mean. I do indeed want $e^{1/4}$ and it's negative, the reciprocal is the one that goes to $e^{-1/4}$ given restrictions on $x$. I was just showing that even if we look at some areas where the expression is defined, we are still led to the conclusion that the limit does not exist. @imranfat